# QtCreator hotkey to move selected block

Tags: qt, qt-creator, hotkeys

In XCode to move selected block you can press "Cmd+]" to right and "Cmd+[" to left, what hotkey in QtCreator do this? In Help I didn't find this function.

Comment: Are You aware of *ctrl-i*? I usually just do *ctrl-a ctrl-i* and let QtC do indentation. Assuming the file is of type QtC can indent Well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a key sequence for Indent/Unindent in Qt Creator. Go to `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard Shortcuts` and specify the shortcuts for this.

Answer (score 9):

The correct answer should be <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> will move the selected block to the right and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> will move it to the left.